# Javascript code to scroll in steps using selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, scroll, selenium-webdriver

How should I scroll in steps instead directly getting to one position using driver.executeScript("scroll(0,1000)");
Tried the code below but it didn't worked..

```
for(var i=10;1<2000;i=+50){
    driver.executeScript("scroll(0,i)");
}
```

It say i is not defined. let me know where am I going wrong

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`driver.executeScript("scroll(0," + i + ")");`

Comment: Thanks but now facing another issue
It times out showing a Fatal error: Call and Retry last allocation failed :(

Comment: That of course is a different matter. My answer was for the question you had asked. Which line throws the error?

Comment: If this answers this question, please accept it as the answer and ask another question.